# Как в gstreamer выделить определенный кусок видео файла и сохранить его аудио часть?

Tags: c++, linux, c

например мне нужно сохранить в файл с пяти секунд до десяти секунд в звуковой файл. В gstreamer так можно? Я хочу сделать для себя редактор, чтобы выделять звуковую речь из фильма и сохранять в файл. потом можно читать субтитры в программе на android и слушать как речь произносится. чтобы удобно отделять файлы, нужно свой софт писать. я немного уже с gstreamer работал, поэтому надо понять, можно ли как-то отделить от одного файла звук с определенным временем в другой файл.

Answer (score 0):

Если смотреть на pipelines отделением звука от видео занимаются demuxer-ы. Для каждого формата контейнера они разные, но есть универсальные вроде qtdemux.

Но в этом случае проще через playbin, чтоб не угадывать кодеки.

[Аудио отделяется и уходит](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/playback/playbin.html?gi-language=c#advanced-usage-specifying-the-audio-and-video-sink) в audio-sink, в который установишь filesink или соединишь с пайпом для кодирования.

Перемотку видео можно осуществлять сигналом SEEK на пайпе или функциями gst_element_seek_simple или gst_element_seek.

Потом подпишись на сигнал convert-sample и дергай там gst_element_query_position пока не пройдет время больше нужного.

Comment: playbin выводит в отдельном окне. а мне надо в том, в котором у меня все виджеты.

Comment: @xverizex sink смени ему и будет там где нужно выводить

Comment: я не пойму и не получается. вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1211190/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4

Comment: @xverizex могу на питоне пример сделать

Comment: хорошо, давайте.

Comment: нужно, чтобы в том же виджете было, что и gtk приложение.

Comment: надо его проматривать при этом?

Comment: да... я пробую тоже у себя сделать, но почему то openh264dec возвращает null почему то.

Comment: может у тебя там не h264?

Comment: я проверил. но дело в том, что gst_element_factory_make возвращает null для openh264dec.

Comment: похоже у меня не установлен openh264. щас  устанавливаю. но кодек в фильме x264, интересно, он подойдет?

Comment: x264 это тотже h264

Comment: а. ну всё равно не работает. возвращает null. а вы скоро сделаете пример на python?