# Не работает видео вывод

Tags: c++, linux, c, gstreamer

Не могу понять как сделать. мне посоветовали попробовать с playbin, и я попробую, а пока посмотрите мой код. здесь я пытаюсь создать приложение, но не появляется сообщение для dbus, которое можно было бы запросить к video overlay.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/video/video.h>

GtkApplication *app;
const char *file_path = "/home/cf/Videos/The.Shadow.1994.1080p.BDRemux.AVC.DTS-HD.MA5.1.Rus.mkv";
//const char *file_path = "/home/cf/Music/01_stellarissuite_creationandbeyond.mp3";

struct widgets {
    GtkWidget *window_main;
    GtkWidget *box_main;
    GtkWidget *area_video;
} w;

struct gstreamer {
    GstElement *pipeline;
    GstElement *source;
    GstElement *audio_convert;
    GstElement *audio_resample;
    GstElement *decode_bin;
    GstElement *audio_sink;
    GstElement *video_sink;
    GstElement *video_mixer;
    GstElement *video_convert;
    GstElement *vsink;
    GstElement *videotest;
    GstBus *bus;
    GstMessage *msg;
} gst;

static void pad_added_handler ( GstElement *src, GstPad *new_pad, gpointer *data ) {
    GstPad *sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad ( gst.audio_convert, "sink" );
    gst_pad_link ( new_pad, sink_pad );
    gst_object_unref ( sink_pad );
}

int ii = 0;
static void message_cb ( GstBus *bus, GstMessage *msg, gpointer data ) {
    g_print ( "%d\n", ii++ );
    switch ( GST_MESSAGE_TYPE ( msg ) ) {
        case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR: {
                        GError *error = NULL;
                        char *debug = NULL;
                        gst_message_parse_error ( msg, &error, &debug );
                        g_print ( "error: from %s %s\n", GST_OBJECT_NAME ( msg->src ), error->message );
                        g_error_free ( error );
                        g_free ( debug );
                    }
                    break;
        case GST_MESSAGE_ELEMENT: {
                      }
                      break;
        case GST_MESSAGE_BUFFERING: {
                            g_print ( "buffering\n" );
                        }
                        break;
    }
}

static GstBusSyncReply create_window ( GstBus *bus, GstMessage *msg, GstPipeline *pipeline ) {

    if ( GST_MESSAGE_TYPE ( msg ) != GST_MESSAGE_ELEMENT ) return GST_BUS_PASS;
    const GstStructure *s = gst_message_get_structure ( msg );
    const char *name = gst_structure_get_name ( s );
    g_print ( "->%s\n", name );
    if ( !strncmp ( name, "prepare-xwindow-id", strlen ( name ) + 1 ) ) {
        gst.vsink = gst_bin_get_by_interface ( GST_BIN ( gst.pipeline ), GST_TYPE_VIDEO_OVERLAY );
        void *window = gtk_widget_get_window ( w.area_video );
        gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle ( GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY ( gst.vsink ), (guintptr) window );
    }else {
        return GST_BUS_PASS;
    }

    gst_message_unref ( msg );
    return GST_BUS_DROP;
}

static void init_player ( ) {

    gst_init ( NULL, NULL );

    gst.pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ( "editor" );

    gst.source = gst_element_factory_make ( "filesrc", NULL );
    gst.audio_convert = gst_element_factory_make ( "audioconvert", NULL );
    gst.audio_resample = gst_element_factory_make ( "audioresample", NULL );
    gst.audio_sink = gst_element_factory_make ( "autoaudiosink", NULL );
    gst.video_sink = gst_element_factory_make ( "autovideosink", NULL );
    gst.video_mixer = gst_element_factory_make ( "videomixer", NULL );
    gst.decode_bin = gst_element_factory_make ( "decodebin", NULL );
    gst.video_convert = gst_element_factory_make ( "videoconvert", NULL );
    gst.videotest = gst_element_factory_make ( "videotestsrc", NULL );


    gst_bin_add_many ( GST_BIN ( gst.pipeline ), gst.decode_bin, gst.source, gst.video_convert, NULL );//gst.audio_convert, gst.audio_resample, gst.audio_sink, gst.video_convert, NULL );
    //gst_element_link_many ( gst.audio_convert, gst.audio_resample, gst.audio_sink, gst.video_sink, gst.video_convert, gst.videotest, NULL );
    gst_element_link_many ( gst.video_sink, gst.video_convert, NULL );
    gst_element_link ( gst.source, gst.decode_bin );
//  gst_element_link_many ( gst.video_mixer, gst.video_sink, NULL );

    g_object_set ( gst.source, "location", file_path, NULL );

    gst_element_set_state(gst.pipeline, GST_STATE_READY);

    g_signal_connect ( gst.decode_bin, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK ( pad_added_handler ), NULL );


    gst.bus = gst_element_get_bus ( gst.pipeline );
    gst_bus_set_sync_handler ( gst.bus, (GstBusSyncHandler) create_window, gst.pipeline, NULL );

    gst_bus_add_signal_watch ( gst.bus );

    g_signal_connect ( gst.bus, "message", G_CALLBACK ( message_cb ), NULL );

    gst_element_set_state ( gst.pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING );

}

static void app_activate_cb ( GtkApplication *app, gpointer data ) {
    w.window_main = gtk_application_window_new ( app );
    gtk_window_maximize ( ( GtkWindow * ) w.window_main );
    w.box_main = gtk_box_new ( GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0 );
    gtk_container_add ( ( GtkContainer * ) w.window_main, w.box_main );
    w.area_video = gtk_drawing_area_new ( );
    gtk_box_pack_start ( ( GtkBox * ) w.box_main, w.area_video, TRUE, TRUE, 0 );

    init_player ( );

    gtk_widget_show_all ( w.window_main );
}

int main ( int argc, char **argv ) {
    app = gtk_application_new ( "org.xverizex.video_editor", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE );
    g_application_register ( ( GApplication * ) app, NULL, NULL );
    g_signal_connect ( app, "activate", G_CALLBACK ( app_activate_cb ), NULL );
    return g_application_run ( ( GApplication * ) app, argc, argv );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите с вывод `GST_DEBUG="*:3"`

Вот вариант с `playbin`, правда на python.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')

from gi.repository import Gtk, Gst
Gst.init(None)
Gst.init_check(None)


class GstWidget(Gtk.Box):
    def __init__(self, uri):
        super().__init__()
        self.connect('realize', self._on_realize)
        self._uri = uri

    def _on_realize(self, widget):
        playbin = Gst.ElementFactory.make('playbin', 'player')
        playbin.set_property("uri", self._uri)
        
        gtksink = Gst.ElementFactory.make('gtksink')
        autoaudio = Gst.ElementFactory.make('autoaudiosink')
      
        playbin.set_property("audio-sink", autoaudio)
        playbin.set_property("video-sink", gtksink)
        
        self.pack_start(gtksink.props.widget, True, True, 0)
        gtksink.props.widget.show()

        # Start the video
        playbin.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)


window = Gtk.ApplicationWindow()
widget = GstWidget('file:///home/eri/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE/Devyataya.2018.WEB-DL.(1080p).Getty.mkv')
widget.set_size_request(1280, 720)

window.add(widget)
window.show_all()

def on_destroy(win):
    Gtk.main_quit()

window.connect('destroy', on_destroy)
Gtk.main()
```

сигналы лови с

```
    bus = playbin.get_bus()
    bus.add_signal_watch()
    bus.connect("message::error", self.on_error)
    bus.connect("message::eos", self.on_eos)
```

Comment: о, спасибо. только как узнать в gtksink какие есть поля? потому что в сишной версии нет поля props.

Comment: вау. у меня запустилось. спасибо.